# mock cdi interceptors during junit tests

Tags: junit, mocking, java-ee-6, cdi, interceptor

I have a complex Java EE 6 app with a web module, an EJB module and some utility jars.

I want to do some integration tests with Junit. Therefore I use the openwebbeans cdi container (Thanks to Mr. Struberg http://struberg.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/controlling-cdi-containers-in-se-and-ee/)
It works perfectly. I can start a complete cdi container in a Junit test.

My problem is that I have some interceptors in my application which cannot run in a Junit test (MQ-, persistence- and transaction-interceptors). So I want to mock these interceptor implementations.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: I think you can use http://arquillian.org/ to test it in real container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whom it may concern ;-)

At the end I solved my issue with clean Java EE techniques. I provided a method which observes the ProcessAnnotatedType event. This method evaluates the type which is processed and if it is one of my interceptors, then I veto the processing.

```java
public void processAnnotatedType(@Observes final ProcessAnnotatedType<?> event, final BeanManager manager) {
    if (event.getAnnotatedType().getJavaClass().equals(PrivilegeCheckingInterceptor.class)) {
        event.veto();
    }       
}
```

Comment: It's way easier to inject a Bean into the interceptor and provide an extended version of it with @Specializes in the test-classpath. DeltaSpike uses that approach to allow customizations of interceptors. This hint doesn't require that you use DeltaSpike (you can just use the same approach).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just test in the container of choice with Arquillian? The other option which comes to mind would be to add in interceptors with mock functionality and exclude the actual interceptor implementation when you start the CDI container.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly, what I want to do: Exclude the original interceptor (in a utility jar). But I do not know how I can do this.

Comment: I haven't done it, but an Interceptor is another type of Bean, you should be able to create a mock one, annotate it with @Alternative and activate the alternative in beans.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can also run tests with embedded OpenEJB.

This link http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/interceptors/ may be useful - perhaps setting property of 'openejb.deployments.classpath.exclude' could help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option of "vetoing" could be through Deltaspike [@Exclude](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/core.html#__exclude) annotation. It can veto beans based on [ProjectStage](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/projectstage.html).

Example:

```
@Exclude(ifProjectStage = ProjectStage.UnitTest.class)
public class MyInterceptor {
}
```

Then in your test you can activate the project stage using Deltapike [test control module](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/test-control.html), example:

```
@RunWith(CdiTestRunner.class)
@TestControl(projectStage = UnitTest.class)
public class TestStageControl {

@Test...

}
```

Comment: UnitTest is the default Stage with CdiTestRunner